# stream_set chunk_size(): The chunk size cannot be larger than laravel 24215454

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, xampp, chunks

I am facing "stream_set_chunk_size(): The chunk size cannot be larger than laravel 24215454"
this error in a Laravel project when I got an error. Do not know why this is raising.

I am using Laravel 8 and XAMPP 3.3.0

[image]

Comment: long shot, but I noticed in [monolog/StreamHandler.php](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/main/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php) line 56 the code checks for a ini setting on memory limit with `ini_get('memory_limit')`, if set it uses max 10% of allowed memory for the chunk size. Check your memory limit setting?

Answer (score 0):

```
stream_set_chunk_size(resource $resourcedata, $maxsize(PHP_INT_MAX))

in php PHP_INT_MAX (integer, not int64) limit is int(2.147.483.647 byte/character).
```

that is, the function does not support data stack above this value, so either the data stack should be reduced, or it should analyze what this 2gb data is from, where it came from, divide it into more than one piece,
should send these parts to the function
Then you have to merge.

Answer (score 0):

The problem become from the `php.ini` file as the package `monolog/monolog` and the `StramHandler` use it on its instruction, and also, it is important to define it in some case.

Type `php --ini` to identify which `php.ini` are loaded by PHP on your server and identify your custom file.

For example, the last on my server is my custom `php.ini`, which override any value of the others:

[image]

Try to change the `memory_limit` value like this :

[image]

Then reload your page / execute any CLI to try it.